# Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::save does not exist in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-8

I have a dropdown list in a data capture view where a join is used in the Controller, but when I am trying to save the record, I am getting a below error.

> `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::save does not exist.`

I have tried to change the eloquent statement to

```
 $energy = DB::table('vehicleslog')->join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')->first();
```

instead of

```
$energy = DB::table('vehicleslog')->join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')->first();
```

however that gives me a below error.

> `Call to undefined method stdClass::save()`

Does anyone know what the correct one is?

**Controller:**

```
  public function index()
    {

        // $energy = Maintenance::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        $energy = DB::table('vehicleslog')->join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')->get();
        $cars = Vehicle::get();
        $staff = Staff::all();
        return view('admin.vmaintenance', compact('energy', 'cars', 'staff'));
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        // $energy = new Maintenance;
        $energy = DB::table('vehicleslog')->join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')->first();
        $cars = Vehicle::all();
        $staff = Staff::get();
        $energy->staff_key = $request->input('staff_key');
        $energy->vehicle_id = $request->input('vehicle_id');
        $energy->log_dt = $request->input('log_dt');
        $energy->admin_time = $request->input('admin_time');
        $energy->driving_time = $request->input('driving_time');
        $energy->work_time = $request->input('work_time');
        $energy->jobcard_count = $request->input('jobcard_count');
        $energy->start_odo = $request->input('start_odo');
        $energy->end_odo = $request->input('end_odo');


        $energy->save();
        return redirect('/vmaintenance')->with('success', 'data added');
    }
```

**View:**

```
<label>Select Vehicle</label>
                    <select name="vehicle_id" >
                        @foreach($cars as $car)
                        <option value="{{ $car->id }}">{{ $car['reg_number'] }}</option>
                @endforeach
                    </select>
```

Comment: `->save()` is only valid with Models. `DB::table(...)->first()` is a `stdClass` object and does not have a `save()` method. If you defined a `VehicleLog` model then did `$energy = VehicleLog::where(...)->first()`, then finally `$energy->save()`, it should work.

Comment: Also, the error `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::save` doesn't make any sense for your code. That would happen if you did `$energy = DB::table(...)->get()`, which returns a Collection, followed by `$energy->save()`.

Comment: @TimLewis, so in the model, use the same statement as my controller but instead of DB, use the table name?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that... Do you know what a model is and how it works? Check the documentation on that: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent, this should show you how to query a model (`$energy = VehicleLog::where(...)->first()`), how to update properties (`$energy->whatever = $request->input('whatever')`) and finally how to update it in the database (`$energy->save()`)

Answer (score 1):

**Eager loading:**

$energy = VehicleLog::with('vehicle')->first();

**Also**:

- this variable never used in your `store()` action:

```php
$cars = Vehicle::all();
$staff = Staff::get();
```

- you can use `fill()` method:

```php
$energy->fill($request->only([
    'staff_key', 'vehicle_id', 'admin_time',
    'driving_time', 'work_time', // ...
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't using a model you'll need to just use an insert statement.

```
DB::table('vehicleslog')->insert([
   'staff_key'   => $request->input('staff_key'),
   'vehicle_id'  => $request->input('vehicle_id'),
   'log_dt'      => $request->input('log_dt'),
   // etc........
)];
```